# Объект. Название переменной объектом

Tags: javascript, wsh

Есть переменная `var name = name();`
Запускает функцию :

```
function name(){
    var random = WScript.CreateObject("System.Random");
    var count_lit = random.Next_2(2, 10);

    var name_i;

    for (var i = 0; i < count_lit; i++){
        name_i += name_builder(name_i);
    }

    return name_i;
}
```

В которой перенаправление на функцию:

```
function name_builder(name){
    var random = WScript.CreateObject("System.Random");
    var number_or_litr = random.Next_2(1, 2);
    // 1 - litr; 2 - number
        if(number_or_litr == 1){
            var abets = random.Next_2(1, 26);
            var litera;
            switch(abets){
                case 1:
                            litera = "a";
                ... 

                case 26:
                            litera = "z";
            };
            var Big_or_mini = random.Next_2(1, 2);
            // 1 - big; 2 - mini 
            if(Big_or_mini == 1){
                name+= litera.toUpperCase();
            }
            else{
                name+= litera;
            }
        }
        else{
            name+= random.Next_2(0, 9).toString();
        }

    return name;
}
```

Задача скрипта  - выдавать "Random" название.
При запуске скрипта возникает ошибка 

"Строка: 101" - это мое указание переменной `var name = name()`

 "Символ: 3"

 "Ошибка: Предполагается наличие объекта"

Кручу - верчу, а понять не могу. Спасибо!

Comment: Не бросайтесь картинками такими, а то могут и не помочь =)

Comment: Не надо выкладывать так много кода. Очевидно же, что достаточно строки где была ошибка и объявления функции `name()`

Comment: @MaximPro Я же без поссыла :) (Учту)

Comment: @PavelMayorov Чуток исправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка *"Предполагается наличие объекта"* возникает когда вы пытаетесь вызвать как функцию или обратиться к свойству у неопределенного значения (`undefined`)

---

Конкретно в вашем случае проблема в том, что вы назвали переменную так же, как и функцию. Переменные и функции находятся в общем пространстве имен.

Поэтому когда вы пишите `name()` - этот самый `name` оказывается не функцией, а переменной. Тот самой, которую вы еще не успели инициализировать, а потому там `undefined`. Отсюда и ошибка.

Назовите переменную по-другому и будет вам щастье.

Comment: Павел, merci !:)